# Searching for Java library or 3rd party library thorugh which I write GUI componets to PDF

Tags: java, user-interface, pdf, printing, swt

I am searching any java library or 3rd party library using which I can make the PDF. Basically I need to generate the documentations which can contain Swing or SWT components. One option is to convert the GUI in Image the convert it into pdf. But wondering is any APIs library exists which can make the GUI components in PDF.

Please, give me any suggestion about this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try with iText library.

you can download it from here : http://itextpdf.com/download.php

Answer (score 1):

If you are making it from XML, there is FOP. For programmatically creating PDFs in Java IText is brilliant.